# get/access each chunk of dask.dataframe(df, chunksize=100)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I used below code to split a dataframe using dask:

```
      result=dd.from_pandas(df, chunksize=75)
```

I use below code to create a custom json file:

```
     for z in result:
            createjson (z)
```

It just didnt work! how can I access to each chunk?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "It just didnt work"? What error is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more native way (feels like there should be) but you can do:

```
for i in range(result.npartitions):
    partition = result.get_partition(i)
    # your code here
```

Answer (score 1):

We do not know what your `createjson` function does, but perhaps it is covered by [`to_json()`](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.to_json).

Alternatively, if you really want to do something unique to each of your partition, and this is not unique to JSON, then you will want the method [`map_partitions()`](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions).

Comment: all partition all the same in terms of json format, only data is different

Comment: createJson only convert dataframe to a json format, not using to_json() though

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what your comment means. I advise that you put more detail into your original question about what your data is like, and what you would like to achieve.